# didDeselectAnnotationView not called when tap on map view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've build a map view controller and everything works fine. When selecting an annotation view on the map, a custom view will be showed on the screen to display some information about that annotation. Tap on the map will deselect that annotation view and hide the custom view.

I get a requirement now, that if there is only one annotation on the view, show the custom view when the map view controller is pushed in. So I simply implement

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view`

when map view finished loading.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView {
    if (self.viewModel.pointsArray.count == 1) {
        GSMapsLocationPoint* point = self.viewModel.pointsArray.lastObject;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self.mapsView viewForAnnotation:point];
        [self mapView:self.mapsView didSelectAnnotationView:annotationView];
    }
}
```

However, when I tap on the map, `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` will not get called. If I tap on that annotation view manually, then `didSelectAnnotationView` will get called correctly.

It seems like that call `didSelectAnnotationView` in code will not change some status so that map view doesn't know there is a annotation view is selected.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `selectAnnotation:` instead of `didSelectAnnotationView:`, try replacing this:

```
[self mapView:self.mapsView didSelectAnnotationView:annotationView];
```

with this:

```
[self.mapsView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES];
```

`didSelectAnnotationView:` will be called by your mapView when the annotation is selected.